# Is the space between plates, in Casimir effect, empty of momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Please correct me if I am wrong. In [Casimir effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect), when two plates are brought very close to each other, there is a Force felt. This force is due to quantum fluctuations.

The space between plates is filled with energy.

My question is: Is the space between  plates, in Casimir effect, empty of momentum?

Comment: It can't be empty of momentum, right? The calculation of the Casimir effect involved integration of ground state over all possible momenta

Comment: What is the value of expected momentum? Does it involve mass of the plates ? Or is this momentum available in space between the plates?

Comment: the expectation value is zero...because the system is very symmetric. However, momentum imparted by waves on the wall is non-zero as it contributes to the Casimir Effect / Attractive force

Comment: @KP99 I am puzzled how it works. What is the value of momentum imparted by waves on the walls ? ( Why don’t you post it as an answer?)

Comment: I will need to verify few things before I can post an answer. But my argument was heuristic. Start from $p=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}=\frac{\pi n}{d}$. The momentum imparted on the wall is $-2p$ and while the time taken on average is $2d$, so the force is $-\frac{\pi n}{d^2}$ and when you sum over all modes you will end up with $F=\frac{\pi}{12d^2}$ which differs from Casimir force by a factor of 2 .  My point is , you can either start from $F=dp/dt$ or $F=-\nabla V$ to actually come up with the qualitative nature of Casimir's Effect